# mtail's own log grows too big and fill the filesystem

Tags: logging

I'm using [mtail](https://github.com/google/mtail) to parse the log to feed metrics in Prometheus.

My mtail rule file (program) had a bug. Mtail produced a verbose log which quickly filled the filesystem.

```
/tmp/mtail.INFO ->
/tmp/mtail.myhostname.jdoe.log.INFO.20181102-175507.32037
```

How can I prevent mtail from filling my production filesystem in such situation ?

How to reduce mtail verbosity?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

```
mtail -progs /path/to/mtail_progs/ -logs /path/to/log  --v=0 -logtostderr -stderrthreshold=WARNING -mtailDebug=0
```

There are multiple options to configure : the glog library and mtail's parser own debugger.

mtail use the [glog](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/glog) package (library) for logging.

> Package glog implements logging analogous to the Google-internal C++ INFO/ERROR/V setup.
>   It provides functions Info, Warning, Error, Fatal, plus formatting variants such as Infof.
>   It also provides V-style logging controlled by the -v and -vmodule=file=2 flags.

The valid names are "INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", and "FATAL"